# xhtml error when working with panelGrid

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces, xhtml, panelgrid

i'm getting an error in xhtml.. 
the code is:

```
<h:form>
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="Name:" />
    <h:inputText value="#{newAuctionWizard.auction.name}" />

    <h:outputLabel value="Description:" />
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{newAuctionWizard.auction.description}" />

    <p:outputLabel for="category" value="Categories from which to pick:" />
    <p:selectOneRadio id="category" value="#{newAuctionWizard.auction.category}"  
     layout="grid" columns="3">
      <f:selectItems value="#{newAuctionWizard.auction.categories}" 
       var="c" itemLabel="#{category}" itemValue="#{category}"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <h:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{newAuctionWizard.cancel()}" />    
    <h:commandButton value="Details" action="newAuctionDetails" />  
  </h:panelGrid>
```

the error appeared after including this section:

```
 <p:outputLabel for="category" value="Categories from which to pick:" />
   <p:selectOneRadio id="category" value="#{newAuctionWizard.auction.category}"  
   layout="grid" columns="3">
     <f:selectItems value="#{newAuctionWizard.auction.categories}" var="c"
      itemLabel="#{category}" itemValue="#{category}"/>
   </p:selectOneRadio>
```

i've added the namespace for p element but still cannot include it in the panelGrid.. can someone tell me what i am doing wrong ? the error is:

```
2017-02-07 14:52:12,275 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "auctioner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"auctioner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#auctionPersistenceUnit\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"auctioner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#auctionPersistenceUnit\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: auctionPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: auctionPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: AUCTION, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(categories)]"}}
```

Comment: Your title states you get an 'error' (title is too generic) but you don not even post WHAT error in your text. That way it is **impossible** to help (and suspicious upvoting here)

Comment: what is the error??

Comment: i've done editing now..sorry:)

Comment: you are referencing in value a list of categories, and that does not exist in auction, see my answer.

Comment: they are in auction.. private List<String> + getters and setters

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE Take atep back and start with some basic jsf tutorials, see the jsf tag page. And basic jpa and basic java...

Answer (score 0):

According to your question the error appears when you try to add selectOneRadio, 
you are using c as var and then you put category as itemLabel, and that is wrong, var is used to reference the object you are showing in f:selectItems, so to define the labels you have to use var, something like this :

```
itemLabel="#{c}"
itemValue="#{c}"
```

and value should be a list of categories you define, and fill it in the managedBean :

```
value="#{newAuctionWizard.categories}"
```

check primefaces : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml

Comment: done.. it says now:  New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."auctioner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."auctioner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.AuctionManagerImpl.WeldInterceptorBindingsService, service jboss.deployment.unit."auctioner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.NewAuctionWizard.WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."auctioner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.UserManagerImpl.WeldInstantiator, service

Comment: this log has nothing to do with the selectOneRadio

Comment: you have to put itemLabel="#{c}" itemValue="#{c}", and make sure that auction.category is a String

Comment: done.. now it says: 2017-02-07 15:48:01,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYDR0011: Couldn't list directory files for C:\Users\user\Downloads\wildfly-10.0.0.Final (1)\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\data\content ... really dont know what's happening

Comment: yeah, sorry.. it says: 
SNAPSHOT.war#auctionPersistenceUnit\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: auctionPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: auctionPersistenceUnit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: AUCTION, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(categories)]"}}

Comment: category and categories are declared in auction(as String, List<String>) + getters and setters

Comment: try to add if (categories == null) {categories = new ArrayList<>();} in getter of categories

Comment: categories are't null.. they are initialized in the constructor from Auctionusing the method add(not like in your link from the comment, where is a init(@PostConstruct) method for iniatilization.. I haven't use @PostConstruct.. can this be the problem ?

Comment: it may be the problem, try to add fetch = FetchType.EAGER to your list, if it doesn't work simply add and fill the list in your manage bean as i suggested before

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE Take atep back and start with some basic jsf tutorials, see the jsf tag page. (@DaianaB)